databricks clusters edit command with a json file
I have many UI clusters in a databricks workspace (Azure), each cluster has spark environment variables. In an automated flow (CI/CD pipelines) i want to add cluster_id value to the existing spark environment variable for each cluster.
I'm using az databricks workspaces list | ConvertFrom-Json command to get a list of workspaces databricks clusters list --output JSON | ConvertFrom-Json command to get all clusters' json configuration. Then i'm adding cluster_id property to the spark_env_vars.
My approach is to save retrieved JSON configuration to a temp file, using PowerShell add cluster_id value to the spark_env_vars section and then using databricks clusters edit --json @$tempFile apply it to a cluster.
The problem i face is that the edit command throws warnings and is not applying an updated JSON. Warning list contains a lot of fields that are part of my JSON and the warning text is like:

Warning: unknown field: cluster_source
Warning: unknown field:   creator_user_name
Warning: unknown field: default_tags
Warning: unknown field: last_restarted_time
Warning: unknown field: last_state_loss_time

It seems to me that those fields are read-only and that's why it fails but i wonder what is another approach to do that? I would like to avoid filtering-out in the code read-only fields and i hope there should be an easier way to add spark environment variable to the existing cluster.
Important is that there are already some other spark env. variables so i have to preserve them and add just cluster_id as an additional one.
In addition, at the end of the warnings list i get an error: Error: failed to reach RUNNING, got TERMINATED: Inactive cluster terminated (inactive for 20 minutes). which seem to me like that edit databricks cli command is trying to start a cluster? - why, when in databricks documentation it is stated that

A cluster can be updated if it is in a RUNNING or TERMINATED state.

and my clusters are in Terminated state when i'm trying to edit their configuration.
Or maybe there is a way to retrieve only writable fields list? I was also thinking to try apply json with only spark environment variables but in the documentation read that i have to provide full json file, like if i provide only spark env vars it will fail/loose all other configuration.
Update:
content of the temp JSON file i'm trying to apply:
{
    "autoscale": {
      "max_workers": 8,
      "min_workers": 1
    },
    "autotermination_minutes": 20,
    "azure_attributes": {
      "availability": "ON_DEMAND_AZURE",
      "first_on_demand": 1,
      "spot_bid_max_price": -1
    },
    "cluster_id": "1111-11111-1kj1k2",
    "cluster_name": "my-cluster-name",
    "cluster_source": "UI",
    "creator_user_name": "***",
    "custom_tags": {
      "cluster-purpose": "compute",
      "driver-node-sku": "Standard_DS3_v2",
      "service": "databricks-cluster",
      "team": "dev",
      "vm-purpose": "db_cluster",
      "worker-node-sku": "Standard_DS3_v2"
    },
    "data_security_mode": "USER_ISOLATION",
    "default_tags": {
      "ClusterId": "1111-11111-1kj1k2",
      "ClusterName": "my-cluster-name",
      "Creator": "***",
      "Vendor": "Databricks",
      "application": "databricks",
      "cost-category": "processing",
      "disaster-recovery": "none",
      "service-classification": "private"
    },
    "driver_node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "enable_elastic_disk": true,
    "enable_local_disk_encryption": false,
    "last_restarted_time": 1844324754432,
    "last_state_loss_time": 1844348533345,
    "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "policy_id": "KDDSFFS8433D",
    "spark_conf": {
      "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "",
      "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "",
      "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "",
      "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "",
      "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": ""
    },
    "spark_context_id": 34950873489578234,
    "spark_env_vars": {
      "AZ_RSRC_GRP_NAME": "rg",
      "AZ_RSRC_NAME": "db-1",
      "AZ_RSRC_PROV_NAMESPACE": "Microsoft.Databricks",
      "AZ_RSRC_TYPE": "workspaces",
      "AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID": "",
      "AZ_TENANT_ID": "",
      "CLIENT_ID": "",
      "CLIENT_SECRET": "",
      "DB_CLUSTER_NAME": "my-cluster-name",
      "DCP_URL": "",
      "DCR_ID": "",
      "DCR_STREAMNAME": "",
      "PROJ_ENV": "dev",
      "LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID": "54jh6m45",
      "LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_KEY": "",
      "DB_CLUSTER_ID": "1111-11111-1kj1k2"
    },
    "spark_version": "14.3.x-scala2.12",
    "start_time": 1844324754432,
    "state": "TERMINATED",
    "state_message": "Inactive cluster terminated (inactive for 20 minutes).",
    "terminated_time": 1844348533345,
    "termination_reason": {
      "code": "INACTIVITY",
      "parameters": {
        "inactivity_duration_min": "20"
      },
      "type": "SUCCESS"
    }
  }

Interestingly that file that i retrieve with edit clusters command to which i'm adding 1 line with the DB_CLUSTER_ID to the spark environment variables is 80 lines and if i go to the databricks workspace cluster and click view JSON is it just 57 lines, so edit command i returning more properties that you can see on the cluster's   page.

post contents of tempFile. And preferably a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Hi can you retrieve the existing Spark configuration for each cluster, modify it to add the new environment variable, and then update the cluster with the modified configuration

@Kashyap - added tempfile content

@DileepRajNarayanThumula - this is exactly the process i'm following and in the edited message you can now see my file

you wanted to updated all the clusters environment vars or only the single cluster?

the code is running a loop, fetching workspaces, then fetching clusters in a workspace and for each cluster adding DB_CLUSTER_ID spark_env_var

Output of get is not a valid input to edit.
Most databricks cli commands that take --json argument, will accept the json that corresponding REST API will accept. In this case /api/2.1/clusters/edit
E.g. to add/update spark env vars.
PS: See the gotcha at bottom.
Create:
~ $ dbk clusters create --no-wait --json '{
  "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
  "spark_version": "14.3.x-scala2.12",
  "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
  "spark_env_vars": {
    "my.name": "kash"
  },
  "aws_attributes": {
    "first_on_demand": 1,
    "availability": "SPOT",
    "zone_id": "us-east-1"
  },
  "num_workers": 5
}'
{
  "cluster_id":"1112-231831-3fzzepx1"
}

~ $ dbk clusters get 1112-231831-3fzzepx1 > old.json

~ $ grep -nA 2 spark_env_vars old.json
26:  "spark_env_vars": {
27-    "my.name":"kash"
28-  },
--
39:    "spark_env_vars": {
40-      "my.name":"kash"
41-    },

~ $

Update:
~ $ dbk clusters edit --json '{
  "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
  "cluster_id": "1112-231831-3fzzepx1",
  "num_workers": 5,
  "spark_version": "14.3.x-scala2.12",
  "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
  "spark_env_vars": {
    "my.name": "1gentlemann",
    "cluster_id": "1112-231831-3fzzepx1"
  }
}'
Error: failed to reach RUNNING, got TERMINATED: Finding instances for new nodes, acquiring more instances if necessary

~ $ dbk clusters get 1112-231831-3fzzepx1 > new.json

~ $ grep -nA 3 spark_env_vars new.json
26:  "spark_env_vars": {
27-    "cluster_id":"1112-231831-3fzzepx1",
28-    "my.name":"1gentlemann"
29-  },
--
36:    "spark_env_vars": {
37-      "cluster_id":"1112-231831-3fzzepx1",
38-      "my.name":"1gentlemann"
39-    },

~ $

Little gotcha is that Databricks updates some things not mentioned in the update JSON. So change your update json to explicitly include all attributes you don't want Databricks to change.
~ $ diff -y old.json new.json
    "availability":"SPOT",         |     "availability":"SPOT_WITH_FALLBACK",
    "first_on_demand":1,           |     "first_on_demand":0,
                                   >     "cluster_id":"1112-231831-3fzzepx1",
    "aws_attributes": {            |     "apply_policy_default_values":false,
      "availability":"SPOT",       <
      "first_on_demand":1,         <
      "zone_id":"us-east-1"        <
    },                             <
                                   >       "cluster_id":"1112-231831-3fzzepx1",

~ $



thanks, but i didn't really get the "gotcha": do you mean that i have to prepare kind of update json file "template" that only contains fields that databricks allows to update and then only fill that json for each cluster?

if you notice, value of "first_on_demand" has changed from 1 to 0. Although the json in dbk clusters edit command does not specify first_on_demand at all.

okay, so from what i've understood the main issue is, as you've mentioned, that "databricks clusters get" command output is not a valid input for "databricks clusters edit command", meaning that only a certain list of properties that is listed in the https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/clusters/edit can be passed to the "edit" commands (even though on that documentation page on the right side we can see an example of the request body that contains all properties - so i find documentation misleading).

Important is also that partial update is possible as mentioned here: https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/clusters/update

not sure what you mean by "documentation page on the right side we can see an example of the request body that contains all properties - so i find documentation misleading", but I don't see the properties you got error for listed in the docs. E.g. cluster_source, default_tags, ...

i meant a request sample on the right side of the cluster update page here: https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/clusters/edit
it shows an example request for the cluster update and contains almost every property of the cluster, so when i look at it i assume when i want to update cluster configuration i have to provide a json with all those fields that are in the example
